# Firefox Upgrade issue

Tags: firefox-addon

I am writing firefox  extension

with following install.rdf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--Copyright 2011, Example -->
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>example</em:id>
    <em:version>1.1</em:version>
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>4.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>6.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>
    <em:name>example</em:name>
    <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
    <em:type>2</em:type>
    <em:description>Example.</em:description>
    <em:creator>Example.</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>http://www.example.com/</em:homepageURL>
    <em:iconURL>chrome://example/content/cm-logo.png</em:iconURL>
    <em:updateURL>https://www.example.com/stat/update.php?ver=2.73</em:updateURL>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

But problem is that if I install it in FF 4 and start FF 5 in same profile location. 
It is showing  as disabled (It is showing as incompatible).

If I directly install in FF 5  it is working fine.

What is wrong in rdf file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Bug.

Version in update url was wrong.

in update url I was giving version 3.6 to 4. :P